# error: Cannot find a column in the entity TextMark that matches with this partial entity field

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have 2 tables in Room Database named as `TextMark` and `Notes` as shown below, When i run project or build it, it give errors of can not find partial entity field.

Notes.java::

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_note")
public class Notes {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cat_id")
    int catId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chapter_id")
    int chapterId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note")
    String notes;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
    String word;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "position")
    int position;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "color")
    String color;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(int catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public int getChapterId() {
        return chapterId;
    }

    public void setChapterId(int chapterId) {
        this.chapterId = chapterId;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

TextMark.java::

```
@Entity(tableName = "text_mark")
public class TextMark {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category")
    int category;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chapId")
    int chapId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "index")
    int index;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text")
    String text;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "background")
    String background;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(int category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getChapId() {
        return chapId;
    }

    public void setChapId(int chapId) {
        this.chapId = chapId;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public void setBackground(String background) {
        this.background = background;
    }
}
```

if you need Database Class then it is below:

```
@Database(entities = {Details.class, Notes.class, Category.class, BookMarked.class, TextMark.class, UnderLine.class},
        exportSchema = false, version = 1)
public abstract class BookDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract BookDao getBookDao();

    private static BookDatabase instance;

    public static synchronized BookDatabase getInstance(Context context, String password) {
        if (instance == null) {
            byte[] bytes = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(password.toCharArray());
            SupportFactory supportFactory = new SupportFactory(bytes);
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), BookDatabase.class,
                    "mydb.db")
                    .createFromAsset("mydb.db")
                    .openHelperFactory(supportFactory)
                    .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                    .setQueryExecutor(AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO())
                    .setTransactionExecutor(AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO())
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

As for Errors on Build is as follows:

> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:15:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     int catId;
> ^
>
> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:17:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     int chapterId;
> ^
>
> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:19:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     String notes;
> ^
>
> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:21:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     String word;
> ^
>
> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:23:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     int position;
> ^
>
> D:\BOOK
> APP\app\src\main\java\com\kingmaker\bookjan\DatabaseHelper\model\Notes.java:25:
> error: Cannot find a column in the entity
> com.kingmaker.bookjan.DatabaseHelper.model.TextMark that matches with
> this partial entity field. If you don't wish to use the field then you
> can annotate it with @Ignore.     String color;
> ^

Comment: If you make your variables to be `public`, does that solve it? I am not sure, but I've been checking [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) link and that appears to be the only difference. If they're package private, as they are now, they might not be accessible by `Room`.

Comment: @Vucko No Difference after making every variables public, still same problem or say error

Comment: Problem is Room Automatically takes `Notes.java` as partial entity of `TextMark.java` as it has same variable types for most variables and it should not happen if i mark(or make) any class with `@Entity` Annotation.

Comment: Great catch :-) makes sense

Comment: Add the code for BookDao *(built project based upon the what's currently in your Q? and compiles fine)*. Also any code (entities/POJO's) (perhaps for details) that have a relationship between TextMark's and Notes. Alternately Remove all but Notes and Textmark from database and BookDao and see if it compiles then one by one add the other Entities and compile.

Comment: @MikeT I found error in BookDao yesterday, I added Mark.java in variable in query of Notes.class.